# About the break of SNP marker position

Tags: r

When we have SNP data like this,

```
  1:168045465:C_T   
  1:2804278:C_G 
  14:88571933:C_T
```

How can we divide this into chromosome, position, allele 1, allele 2 (e.g., 1,  168045465,  C,  T)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple function to do the reformatting for you:

```
x = c("1:168045465:C_T", "1:2804278:C_G", "14:88571933:C_T")
refmt = function(snp){
  temp1 = unlist(strsplit(snp, ":"))
  temp2 = unlist(strsplit(temp1[3],"_"))
  temp = c(Chr = temp1[1], pos = temp1[2], a1 = temp2[1], a2 = temp2[2])
  return(temp)
}
op = as.data.frame(t(sapply(x, refmt)))
```

Which yields:

```
> op
                Chr       pos a1 a2
1:168045465:C_T   1 168045465  C  T
1:2804278:C_G     1   2804278  C  G
14:88571933:C_T  14  88571933  C  T
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr`'s `extract` to extract data into different columns using regex.

```
tidyr::extract(df, V1, c('chromosome', 'position', 'allele1', 'allele2'),
                       '(\\d+):(\\d+):(.*)_(.*)')

#  chromosome  position allele1 allele2
#1          1 168045465       C       T
#2          1   2804278       C       G
#3         14  88571933       C       T
```

You can also use the same regex in base R `strcapture`

```
proto <- data.frame(chromosome=integer(), position=integer(), 
                    allele1=character(),allele2 = character())

strcapture('(\\d+):(\\d+):(.*)_(.*)', df$V1, proto)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("1:168045465:C_T", "1:2804278:C_G", "14:88571933:C_T"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you so much!